# how to disable a specific date in the date range picker? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, daterangepicker

I searched and I found that there is no any function through which we ca disable the a specific date in the `dateRangePicker`

```
final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? _startDate;
  DateTime? _endDate;

Future<void> _selectDateRange(BuildContext context) async {
  final initialDateRange = DateTimeRange(
    start: _startDate ?? DateTime.now(),
    end: _endDate ?? DateTime.now(),
  );





final DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime? firstDate;
DateTime? lastDate;

if (widget.selectedLeaveType == 'earned') {
  // User cannot select previous dates
  firstDate = currentDate;
  lastDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1, 3, 31);
} else if (widget.selectedLeaveType == 'sick') {
  // User can select up to the last three months
  firstDate = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month - 2, 1);
  lastDate = currentDate;
}

final pickedDateRange = await showDateRangePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDateRange: initialDateRange,
  firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
  lastDate: lastDate ?? DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1),
);

if (pickedDateRange != null) {
  setState(() {
    _startDate = pickedDateRange.start;
    _endDate = pickedDateRange.end;
    print("Selected leave type: ${widget.selectedLeaveType.toString()}");
    _textEditingController.text =
        '${_startDate!.toString().split(' ')[0]} - ${_endDate!.toString().split(' ')[0]}';
  });

  // Call the onDateRangeSelected callback function with the selected start and end dates
  if (widget.onDateRangeSelected != null) {
    widget.onDateRangeSelected!(_startDate, _endDate);
  }
}
}
```

I have also tried to use `selectableDayPredicate` in the `dateRangePicker` but it is not available in it.

can anyone please tell me, what is the another way to disable a specific date in the `dateRangePicker`?

Comment: Maybe you can check out [Syncfusion's Data Range Picker](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/daterangepicker/overview), it does offer this functionality. But check out licensing terms because it is free only if you meet some conditions, otherwise you have to pay for it.